# How to shape html switches beautifully?

Tags: html, forms

I need to beautifully design the "switches". Found an example on one site. How can I do the same? Please give a link to a similar example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Switches</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
    <p><input name="tech" type="radio" value="computer" checked>compute</p>
    <p><input name="tech" type="radio" value="xbox">xbox</p>
    <p><input name="tech" type="radio" value="playstation">playstation</p>
    <p><input name="tech" type="radio" value="Game">Game</p>
    <p><input name="tech" type="radio" value="TV">TV</p>

  </form> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of what I want to get.
[image]

Comment: Its a bit more complex, but you could have div elements instead of radio elements and then have a hidden input controlled by JS. You'd have significantly more control over styling. Is this an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this.

You hide the radio circle but if you select it (by the label) you change the style of the label.

```css
input{
    display: none;
}

input + label{
    font-size: 14px;
    border: #9c94bb 1px solid;
    width: 130px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

input:checked + label{
    background: #ece8ff;
}

form{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Switches</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <p>
      <input name="tech" type="radio" value="computer" id="computer" checked>
      <label for="computer">computer</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name="tech" type="radio" value="xbox" id="xbox">
      <label for="xbox">xbox</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name="tech" type="radio" value="playstation" id="playstation">
      <label for="playstation">playstation</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name="tech" type="radio" value="Game" id="game">
      <label for="game">Game</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name="tech" type="radio" value="TV" id="tv">
      <label for="tv">TV</label>
    </p>
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I noticed that "input" is hiding (input {
    display: none;
}), and if I have "text input"? How to hide "input" only radio buttons?

Comment: input[type="radio"]{
  display:none
}